# Is there any integral function to calculate some exponential functions in Julia?

Tags: julia

I would like to create an expected value (continues). Therefore, I need to make an integral with infinite limits.

For example:

`integrate(exp(2*x+1),-Inf:Inf)`

How could I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite package for numerical integration is FastGaussQuadrature.jl:

https://github.com/ajt60gaibb/FastGaussQuadrature.jl

Just sharing yet another package for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages in Julia that allow you to do this. You can use [Cubature.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/cubature) for instance. It requires you to transform infinite interval into a finite one via [change of variables](https://github.com/stevengj/cubature/blob/master/README.md#infinite-intervals).

Here is an example (I use other function than the one in your example as your original integral is divergent):

```
using Cubature
f(x) = exp(-x^2)
res = hquadrature(y -> f(y/(1-y^2))*(1+y^2)/((1-y^2)^2), -1, 1)
```

And you can now check that we are close to the correct result for this choice of `f`:

```
julia> res[1] - sqrt(pi)
2.220446049250313e-16
```

Answer (score 1):

QuadGK.jl does the change of variable automatically, so you can just feed it the (1D) infinite integral directly.

Comment: This is true, but Cubature.jl is a bit safer (and has more functionality in general) and that is why I have recommended it. For the original integral `cubature` returns `Inf` and `quadgk` throws `DomainError` which could be confusing.